# Rollback transactions

Tags: sql, node.js, transactions

I have a service where I am doing something like below

```
1. await users = user.read(); // reads all users; 
2. await task = task.create('taskId') // creates a new task
3. await tasks = task.create(users,task) // add the above task for all users ;
```

### Problem

1. If code line 3 fails, i.e. adding tasks to all users then code line 2 should roll back.

### Edit 1

### What I have tried.

As pointed out by [delerik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150075/delirek) deleting is an option but I have a feeling there is a better way to do this. Imagine n tables then it will be a mess.

Comment: well, you don't have any transactions here, so I'm not sure if saying that you need to rollback transaction is okay, but.. the first dummy solution is to wrap task 3 into try catch and when task 3 fails just call delete on task 2

Comment: Thanks @delirek. In my understanding I chose to call it a transaction as line 1,2  and 3 are internally making DB calls. Do you read it differently? + Yes delete is one option I have thought of but I'm guessing there is a better way to do it with regards to performance?